# SecureStorage create failed in ionic native

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic2

I'm trying to use SecureStorage in ionic-native

```
let secureStorage: SecureStorage = new SecureStorage();
secureStorage.create('my_store_name')
 .then(
   () => console.log('Storage is ready!'),
   error => console.log(error)
);
```

but I'm getting the error "`undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new cordova.plugins.SecureStorage(res, rej, store)')`" on iphone 5s

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have this code in a provider and it works for me...:

```js
...    
public virtual: boolean = true;
    public ss: SecureStorage;

    constructor(
        private _http: Http,
        private _config: ConfigurationService,
        private _events: Events) {
       
        this.virtual = Device.device.isVirtual;
        if (this.virtual !== undefined && !this.virtual) {
            console.log(`Using SecureStorage`); 
            this.ss = new SecureStorage();
            this.ss.create('ss') 
                .then(
                () => {
                    this.virtual = false;
                    this._events.publish('StorageReady'); 
                },
                error => console.log(error)
                );
        } else {
            console.log(`Using localstorage for simulation`); 
            this.virtual = true;
        }
    } ....
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. My issue was fixed after installing the SecureStorage ionic-native plugin again..